# Is there a reference for boundedness of smooth canonically polarized varieties over Z (No...)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces, stacks

In Kollár's paper *Quotient spaces modulo algebraic groups*, Kollár mentions right above Theorem 1.8 that the stack $\mathcal M_P$ of smooth canonically polarized varieties over Spec $\mathbb Z$ with fixed Hilbert polynomial $P$ is of finite type over Spec $\mathbb Z$. (Edit: this is not claimed in the paper.)

I couldn't find a reference for this fact. Is it well-known, or easy to prove?

(Note that the theory of Hilbert schemes tells us that $\mathcal M_P$ is a locally finite type algebraic stack over $\mathbb Z$. It is the fact that $\mathcal M_P$ is in fact of finite type over Spec $\mathbb Z$ which I'm asking about (Edit: This is not known currently.). It is well-known to follow from Matsusaka's big theorem in characteristic zero, i.e., the algebraic stack $\mathcal M_{\mathbb Q}$ is of finite type over $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: Maybe I have a preprint, but in my version, Koll'ar only states that this is locally of finite type, not of finite type.

Comment: @JasonStarr You're right. I must have confused the statements of 1.7 and 1.8. I guess it's not well-known, and in fact probably still unknown whether $\mathcal M_P$ is of finite type or not for $\deg P \geq 3$.